# iOS URL schemes and emails

Tags: ios, url, url-routing, email

So asking this because I have not found a version of this in one place that describes the outcome, or I don't know what to search for.

Here is the question.  I have a app that I wrote and incorporated a URL scheme, let's say it's named ABC, so the url scheme would be:

```
ABC:/this/is/the/data
```

So, I want to send out a email to folks that would open my app, so the link is pretty straight forward.  But, what if I want them to goto the website in the case they don't have my app, way www.abc.com/this/is/the/data.  Is there a way to code my email so that both are possible? (That if the app is present it opens, if not the site opens?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In an email there is not a way to do it. My approach would be to send them to your website and in your website page have the [iOS smart banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) for your app. This will give them the option to open the app or download the application.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

The other approach would be to include 2 links in your email and explain that if you have the app to click the specific link. If not then click the website link.

Comment: I wonder if you could send an HTML email containing the iOS Smart Banner tag?

Comment: @David Maybe, but I believe it is safari that does the meta processing for the smart banner. I don't believe Mail does it.